# Sqoop Incremental Import for New Records

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have a table consisting emp_id from 1 to 10 in which `emp_Id = 6` is not present and I have done a incremental Sqoop on append mode by creating Sqoop job.
After this,Next I wanted to add two new emp_id came i.e `emp_id=6` and `emp_id = 12`.
Now my question is will incremental sqoop import the `emp_id =6` or will it import only `emp_id = 12`?

Comment: Can you put what have you written in your Sqoop Job in your question? You can visit [this link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/10710/sqoop-incremental-import-working-fine-now-i-want-k.html)

Comment: This is the scenario, some where I have read that sqoop will import only  increasing data , so I think it will only append emp-id = 12

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined `--check-column emp_id` with `--incremental append` (and you have wrote emp_id=6 and other values null) your job will be write only emp_id=12 record. But if the --check-column parameter does not find a value 6 in existing records, the job will write also the emp_id=6 record.

If you want append new records and/or modify existing ones consider the `--last-value` parameter. [See this](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports). 
Be careful that with job created, the last value is already saved in /tmp sqoop directory. In this case I suggest you to use sqoop import simply, I verified that it works better.